# how to save picture in excel with ruby

Tags: ruby, excel, export

I have pictures in excel, how to export pictures with ruby

i want to extract the images and save them as image files

Comment: You want to extract the images and save them as image files?

Comment: I think the title contradicts the question. The picture is being saved to excel, but the pictures are in excel and need to be exported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand the question. There is an image (quite possibly an OLE object) in an excel workbook, and you want to save it as an individual image file. The only way I know of to do that is to control Excel itself using the win32ole gem, here's a start (untested, as I run linux):

```
require 'win32ole'
xl = WIN32OLE.new("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open('c:\file.xls')
wb.SaveAs('c:\file.html', 44)
xl.Quit
```

Then I would pull out the images from the resulting image directory.